# Cannot create index for LaTeX/PDF output

Tags: bookdown

I followed the [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latex-index.html) instruction to create the indexing. Although the code ran without error, it was not showing the index in the pdf output. There is also instruction [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/149). I must be doing something silly!

The reproducible code is here:

```
#####################
##### index.Rmd #####
#####################

--- 
title: "Linear Models using R"
author: 
- J Smith
- ABC Inc
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
bookdown::gitbook:
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin=0.8in
bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: null
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: yes
includes:
  in_header:
    - \usepackage{makeidx}
    - \makeindex  
  after_body:
    - \printindex
documentclass: book
classoption: openany
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "Linear Models using R"
---


####################
###### 01.Rmd ######
####################

# Model

This is an R Markdown\index{rmarkdown} document\index{document}.

This book\index{book} describes linear\index{linear} model.

In this chapter\index{chapter}, we will discuss polynomial\index{polynomial} model.


# Index{-}

####### Error
####### \printindex
```

Just to add clarity, lines with mulitple '#' are comments or file names. Note if I run simple `\printindex` at the end of the document (commented above), it shows the following error:

`! Undefined control sequence. \printindex`

The `sessionInfo()` is here:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /cm/shared/apps/R/3.4.1/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /cm/shared/apps/R/3.4.1/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     bookdown_0.7.15  digest_0.6.15    withr_2.1.2     
 [5] R6_2.2.2         jsonlite_1.5     git2r_0.18.0     magrittr_1.5    
 [9] evaluate_0.11    httr_1.3.1       stringi_1.2.2    curl_3.1        
[13] rmarkdown_1.10.8 devtools_1.13.4  htmldeps_0.1.1   tools_3.4.1     
[17] stringr_1.3.1    xfun_0.3         yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.4.1  
[21] memoise_1.1.0    htmltools_0.3.6  knitr_1.20.8
```

Answer (score 3):

The YAML is not specified correctly. The following works for me.

## index.Rmd

```
--- 
title: "Linear Models using R"
author: 
- J Smith
- ABC Inc
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin=0.8in
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: null
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: yes
    includes:
      after_body: after_body.tex
      in_header: include_header.tex
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
---

# Model

This is an R Markdown\index{rmarkdown} document\index{document}.

This book\index{book} describes linear\index{linear} model.

In this chapter\index{chapter}, we will discuss polynomial\index{polynomial} model.
```

## include_header.tex

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

## after_body.tex

```
\printindex
```

And at the console of your book directory run

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book")
```

Output:

[image: index]

Comment: Thanks @Emi Tanaka for the corrections and suggestions. I think your suggestion is equivalent to add those lines in the YAML header directly without creating new files. I have now added these in my codes. I have tried both ways. It is running, but I am still getting a blank index page. I am wondering without /printindex (as in LaTeX) in an appropriate place, how bookdown will know where to print the index.

Comment: The `after_body` YAML would know to put the latex at the end. It is working for me The pdf output [here](https://ufile.io/blmaq). Maybe try updating your latex and bookdown?

Comment: Thanks @Emi, your page looks perfect. Another issue that I did not mention is the error I am getting while running from the console: `Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found`. I tried RStudio instead with both `XeLatex` and `pdfLaTeX`. I have earlier issues where installing pandoc independently conflicts with rmarkdown, so I better avoid it. Did you try running it from RStudio?

Comment: If you use RStudio, there is no need to install Pandoc separately: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/installation.html

Comment: @user10141733 You can symlink RStudio's Pandoc (and I recommend so) if you have to use rmarkdown in a non-RStudio environment, such as in your terminal: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie for clarifying couple of things. It is recommended, as shown by Emi, to use external files. With RStudio, separate pandoc installation is not required. Copying the pandoc binaries to the usr/bin and then calling from R command line does not show `pandoc` error. Now, from the command line as well as RStudio, the pdf is created perfectly except the index. Please submit the sessionInfo() if you are responding.

Comment: Hello @yihui-xie, could you please help me with a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296563/bookdown-issue-when-compiling-a-pdf-book-but-not-a-gitbook-i-receive-this-erro